# Star sizing RowDefintions not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having some issues when trying to get a `Grid` with 2 `RowDefinitions` to always have the same `height` regardless of whether or not the `Image` inside that row is `null` or not. What currently happens is that if the `Image` is `null`, that row shrinks to practically nothing. I want that row to ALWAYS be the same size though.

I have the following `Grid` set up in my Windows Store App:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*" x:Name="BB0RowADef" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="DebugGrid"  Grid.Row="0" Loaded="DebugGrid_Loaded">
        <Image Source="{Binding RepGrid[0].TaskStatus, Converter={StaticResource TaskStatusToIcon}}"  Stretch="Uniform" />
    </Grid>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RepGrid[0].TaskName}" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

And in my code-behind to check the `ActualHeight` I have the following `Loaded` method:

```
private void DebugGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid senderGrid = (Grid) sender;
    Grid parentGrid = (Grid)senderGrid.Parent;
    Debug.WriteLine("Row 0 Height: " + parentGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height.ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine("Row 0 Actual: " + parentGrid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight.ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine("Row 1 Height: " + parentGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height.ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine("Row 1 Actual: " + parentGrid.RowDefinitions[1].ActualHeight.ToString());
}
```

What is confusing me is the output is the following:

```
Row 0 Height: 3*
Row 0 Actual: 7
Row 1 Height: 1*
Row 1 Actual: 20
```

That doesn't make any sense. If Row 0 is 3*, it should be 3 times the size of Row 1, but that isn't happening. What would cause this?

Comment: Parent grid is the root element of your page? If not, what's the container of that grid?

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code I get:

> Row 0 Height: 3*
>   Row 0 Actual: 234
>   Row 1 Height: *
>   Row 1 Actual: 78

Modified the code since I don't have the image to load and you are experiencing the problem when no image is loaded.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"
                       x:Name="BB0RowADef" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="DebugGrid"
          Loaded="DebugGrid_Loaded"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Background ="Cyan">
        <Image Source="" />
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Background="Beige" Text="{Binding RepGrid[0].TaskName}"
               Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```